# Why does Givens rotation avoid iteration and Jacobi rotation doesn't in case of reducing a symmetric matrix to tridiagonal?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I am currently implementing symmetric matrix reduction to tridiagonal.
I read that Givens rotation avoids iteration when it is used for reducing a matrix to tridiagonal whereas Jacobi rotation is iterative. Givens rotation try to annihilate the element $a_{i-1j}$ by a rotation in $ij-$plane and Jacobi rotation try to annihilate the element $a_{ij}$ by a rotation in $ij-$plane. But just because of that, how can Givens rotation avoid iteration as both use same equations?

$a^{'}_{rp}=ca_{rp} - sa_{rq}$

$ a^{'}_{rq}=ca_{rp} + sa_{rq}$

$ a^{'}_{pp}=c^{2}a_{pp}+s^{2}a_{qq}-2sca_{pq}$

$a^{'}_qq=s^{2}a_{pp}+c^{2}a_{qq}+2sca_{pq}$

$a^{'}_{pq}=(c^{2}-s^{2})a_{pq}+sc(a_{pp}-a_{qq})$

Now in Jacobi rotation , they try to zero out $a^{'}_{pq}$ and in Givens rotation they try to zero out $a^{'}_{p-1q}$ i.e.,$ a^{'}_{rq}$.

Answer (score 7):

The fundamental difference is that the Jacobi method attempts to reduce the matrix to *diagonal* form, and successive rotations undo previously set zeros, but the off-diagonal elements successively get smaller and smaller (thus it is an "iterative" method).

The sequence of Givens rotations tries to do something easier:  It reduces the matrix to *tridiagonal* form.  It can do this in a finite number of steps.  If you still need the eigenvalues and eigenvectors, you can work with that tridiagonal form to find eigenvalues; that calculation still requires iteration, but if you are interested only in a small number of eigenvalues (say the largest ones) that may be a reasonable approach.

Of course, if your goal is explicitly just reduction to tridiagonal, then Givens rotation is clearly superior to the iteration of Jacobi rotations. However, for that purpose, the Householder algorithm, in which each transformation annihilates part of a whole column and the corresponding row, is clearly superior to the Givens method (just as stable, and twice as efficient).  See sections 11.1 and 11.3 of Numerical Recipes for details.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Yes, I understand these things. Confusion I have is, why Givens rotation doesn't change the already zeroed out elements but Jacobi rotation, when both are based on same equation. How can trying to annihilate the element $a_{i−1j}$ by a rotation in ij−plane avoid affecting other elements which are zeroed out?

Comment: Could you please help to understand that? Thank you

Comment: The elements already set to zero are, in each successive step, homgeneous linear combinations of themselves and other elements already set to zero. Thus once an element and its transpose element have been set to zero, they remain zero on the next step. Try it out one a 4x4 matrix; that is the smallest non-trivial size.

Comment: Thank you for your response. But in Jacobi rotation also they use the same formula. SO in Jacobi rotation also if you follow the same order of annihilating the elements, the elements already set to zero should be homogeneous linear combinations of themselves and other elements already set to zero. Right? But value changes in Jacobi rotation. I am totally confused.

Comment: Both rotations are designed for completely different things and use different formulas. How do they use the same formula?

Comment: $a^{'}_{rp}=ca_{rp} - sa_{rq}$, 

$ a^{'}_{rq}=ca_{rp} + sa_{rq}$, 

$ a^{'}_{pp}=c^{2}a_{pp}+s^{2}a_{qq}-2sca_{pq}$, 

$a^{'}_qq=s^{2}a_{pp}+c^{2}a_{qq}+2sca_{pq}$, 

$a^{'}_{pq}=(c^{2}-s^{2})a_{pq}+sc(a_{pp}-a_{qq})$. 

Now in Jacobi rotation , they try to zero out $a^{'}_{pq}$ and in Givens rotation they try to zero out $a^{'}_{p-1q}$ i.e.,$ a^{'}_{rq}$. (from numeric recipes). 

Is my understanding correct?

Comment: @AlgebraicPavel Am I wrong?

Comment: Both Jacobi and Givens rotations (real) have the form $Q=\begin{bmatrix}c&s\\-s&c\end{bmatrix}$ where $c^2+s^2=1$. While the Givens rotation attempts to make a transformation $Q^T\begin{bmatrix}a\\b\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}r\\0\end{bmatrix}$ (such that $r^2=a^2+b^2$), that is, to introduce zeros in a vector, the Jacobi rotation is constructed to diagonalize a $2\times 2$ matrix, that is, $Q^T\begin{bmatrix}a&b\\b&c\end{bmatrix}Q=\begin{bmatrix}d&0\\0&e\end{bmatrix}$.